# TypeError when trying to set a DB value

Tags: python, database, mongodb, flask, mongodb-atlas

I'm trying to get my Flask server to update to a Mongo Atlas DB on request. When a request is passed with the required arguments, it will post to a Discord webhook then attempt to update DB values.

Example: Going to https://(redacted for privacy)/(redacted for privacy)?iid=123&username=wow&price=22 with JUST the webhook code (doesn't touch DB) will do this:
[(sent to discord webhook)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPQvk.png) and give a success message (outputs as 200 in the console).

But when I enable the DB code, the same link will through a `500` error. Anything I can do? The console outputs as;

```
   balance = mycol.find_one({"UserID": uid})['balance']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I don't understand why this won't work. Here's the code that works, but only posts to the webhook (commented stuff is DB related):

```
  #balance = mycol.find_one({"UserID": uid})['balance']
  #res = mycol.find_one({"UserID": uid})
  #newvalues = { "$set": { "UserID": uid, "balance": int(balance) + int(cashback_amt)} }
  #mycol.update_one(res, newvalues)
  img_url = f"https://www.roblox.com/bust-thumbnail/image?userId={uid}&width=420&height=420&format=png"

  data = {
    "content" : "**New purchase!**",
    "username" : "robate"
  }

  data["embeds"] = [
    {
        "description" : f"**ItemID**: `{item_id}`\n**Item Price**: `{price}`\n**Item Cashback**: `{cashback_amt}`",
        "title" : "New purchase made",
        "color": 65311,
        "thumbnail": {"url": img_url}
    }
  ]
  
  result = requests.post(purclog, json = data)
  return jsonify({"res": True})
```

And the non-working DB included code:

```
  balance = mycol.find_one({"UserID": uid})['balance']
  res = mycol.find_one({"UserID": uid})
  newvalues = { "$set": { "UserID": uid, "balance": int(balance) + int(cashback_amt)} }
  mycol.update_one(res, newvalues)
  img_url = f"https://www.roblox.com/bust-thumbnail/image?userId={uid}&width=420&height=420&format=png"

  data = {
    "content" : "**New purchase!**",
    "username" : "robate"
  }

  data["embeds"] = [
    {
        "description" : f"**ItemID**: `{item_id}`\n**Item Price**: `{price}`\n**Item Cashback**: `{cashback_amt}`",
        "title" : "New purchase made",
        "color": 65311,
        "thumbnail": {"url": img_url}
    }
  ]
  
  result = requests.post(purclog, json = data)
  return jsonify({"res": True})
```

Any help is severely appreciated. Have a good day!

EDIT: The UserID is defined here:

```
try:
    uid = requests.get(f"https://api.roblox.com/users/get-by-username?username={username}").json()['Id']
  except:
    return
  balance = mycol.find_one({"UserID": uid})['balance']
```

Comment: The two snippets you posted are identical.  The implication here is that `uid` is not found.  Where did `uid` come from?

Comment: The snippets are mostly the same, but the top code is commented also ive fixed it

Comment: Have you printed `uid` so you can double-check it's actually contained in the database? And, by the way, you shouldn't do the query twice.  Since you fetch the whole record in `res = mycol.find_one({"UserID": uid})`, just do `balance = res['balance']` after that, after checking that it actually fetched a record.

Comment: the biggest mistake is `except: return`. You may have some error but you can't see it. And it returns `None` which can make problem. You could at least display error `except Exception as ex: print(ex)`

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).